# Is SD2209 the same as TMC2209 stepper drivers?

Tags: stepper-driver, tmc2209

While shopping for TMC2209 stepper drivers I found advertisements "SD2209". Is this the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, the SD2209 is not a clone of or another name for the TMC2209, but is a board with a TMC2209 on it setup to be used as a drop-in replacement for other stepper drivers. See e.g. [this SD2209 a drop-in replacement for Pololu style drivers](http://www.panucatt.com/mobile/product.aspx?ProductCode=sd2209):

[image]

Comment: It must be designed for boards where no firmware update is envisioned: usually the trimmer is on the bottom side because unnecessary, but here they sacrificed useful heatsink surface to show the trimmer. Also, they didn't expose the DEBUG pin, which would be the third hole in a triangle with the other two on the short side and which is useful for sensorless homing, which makes sense if no firmware update is expected.

Comment: 2.7 A max current is peak, not RMS, which is misleading... but probably irrelevant if used as drop-in replacement with preset trimmer to the usual 0.8 A